# php :How to generate 2D array from mysql SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion, tree

I have some questions , please help me.

1. In PHP/MySQL I have a query that I want to generate 2D array, how can I do it ?
2. I hava a php array code, like this:

   ```
   $menu = Array( // I wanna to get data from a SQL SELECT.
       Array('id'=>1,'title'=>'Menu 1',          'parent_id'=>null),
       Array('id'=>2,'title'=>'Sub 1.1',         'parent_id'=>1),
       Array('id'=>3,'title'=>'Sub 1.2',         'parent_id'=>1),
       Array('id'=>4,'title'=>'Sub 1.3',         'parent_id'=>1),
       Array('id'=>5,'title'=>'Menu 2',          'parent_id'=>null),
       Array('id'=>6,'title'=>'Sub 2.1',         'parent_id'=>5),
       Array('id'=>7,'title'=>'Sub Sub 2.1.1',   'parent_id'=>10),
       Array('id'=>8,'title'=>'Sub 2.2',         'parent_id'=>5),
       Array('id'=>9,'title'=>'Menu 3',          'parent_id'=>null),
       Array('id'=>10,'title'=>'Menu 3',          'parent_id'=>null),
   );
   ```

   How could I to generate this simple array using mysql ?

   ```
   <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
       die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("mydb");

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

   //this is wrong,but I wanna to reach this effect↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
       echo "Array('id'=>$row["id"],'title'=>'$row["title"]','parent_id'=>$row["parent_id"]),"

   }

   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with one zero indices and append arrays to it.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();

for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $i;
    $row[] = $i*3;
    $row[] = $i*9;

    $data[] = $row;
}

var_dump($data);

--output:--
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(9)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
    [2]=>
    int(18)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(9)
    [2]=>
    int(27)
  }
}
```